# I lost my dog. How do I get him back & will he hate me?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I was playing in single player as Franklin, and my dog got out of the car we were in and ran off barking. I didnt get out as there was a random event I wanted to see and take care of. Long story short, I left him there.

How can I get him back?  Will this hurt our friendship or make him less happy?

Comment: This happened to the LPer I was watching while he was mid-chase during a mission. The dog just jumped out of the car pretty much but he kept driving. The dog is present in later videos, so I figure he comes back somehow.

Comment: Chop is a good dog. Why let him go? LOL

Comment: Is he not back at the house?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you leave chop anywhere he will just spawn back at your own house. The iFruit app for ipad seems to be the only way to raise the like of chop anyway, so leaving him somewhere ingame does not seem to hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Just go back to Chop's house, you will find him there.